# How to cache HuggingFace model and tokenizer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm using hugginface model `distilbert-base-uncased` and tokenizer `DistilBertTokenizerFast` and I'm loading them currently using `.from_pretrained()`

I want cache them so that they work without internet was well.

I tried `cache_dir` parameter in the `from_pretrained()` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean? It should work. You run the code, it downloads the files and after that no internet should be needed? You want to change the dir these files should be stored?

Comment: I think it gets stored in ~./cache/huggingface/transformers but whenever I call the model/tokenizer to process the input, it gives an error saying it cant connect to internet

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? I.e. is it a valid complaint/error message? I remember some similar problem I had, I think there was something wrong with my install. AFAIK it should work without relative path etc.

Comment: I have solved the problem and I have posted a solution below. No, there is no problem in the installation. The error message was an HTTP error saying it couldn't reach a particular site or API (I'm not sure) but the solution below solves the issue. The tokenizer and model were then cache and ran without the internet as well.

Comment: I saw your answer, but it shouldn't be so complicated, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't apply to others. If you need all that so "normal" use of HF doesn't give you errors, then there is something wrong with HF, hence my observation that there is something wrong with the installation. :shrug:

Comment: Might be, but I'm not able to clearly diagnose the problem as the traceback call wasn't much helpful. For those who might face similar problem, they can follow my answer I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by these steps:

1. Use `.from_pretrained()` with `cache_dir = RELATIVE_PATH`  to download the files
2. Inside RELATIVE_PATH folder, for example, you might have files like these:[image]
   open the json file and inside the url, in the end you will see the name of the file like `config.json`. Copy this name
3. Rename the other file present in the image to the text which you copied (in our example `config.json`)
4. Repeat these steps for other files
5. Run `.from_pretrained(RELATIVE_PATH, local_files_only = True)` in your model/tokenizer.

This solution should work

Comment: You only need `local_files_only = True`. See this gist https://gist.github.com/vatai/e289f1769f21f12ce6acdd6afcb4a8f0

Comment: ohh, its good then. So, this might be an easier solution for those trying to cache.